# How can I connect four 2560x1440 monitors to a Macbook Pro?

Tags: multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I am thinking about buying a new Macbook Pro but I want to be sure that I can connect four 2560x1440 monitors to it without a problem.

I need the monitors to each be a logical screen in the OS. In other words, I don't want the top bar to span the entire array of monitors, only one.

Is this possible?

If three displays is easier than four, that might be okay too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display#Daisy_Chaining

You can get three chained together. It sounds incredibly expensive, but its possible. You have to use thunderbolt.

Comment: "You can get three chained together" So is four possible?

Comment: Three total. I don't know if you want to count the built in display on the laptop; I suppose that would make four. But you can have three external displays.